# Problem in creating Cypress code coverage report for E2E tests

Tags: code-coverage, cypress, e2e-testing

I have been using cypress for E2E testing and wanted to create a full coverage report, to generate a complete coverage report you are required to run all cypress tests together. The first test calls the task `resetCoverage` in the start and `saveCoverage` at the end of the test and every test that follows with coverage task `combineCoverage` at the end.

The issue I am facing is running all the tests together hangs the system as well as fails due to timeout errors, it runs perfectly when running standalone tests. I wanted to know if there is a way to create a full report by running the cypress tests manually one by one without every test resetting the previous coverage report but rather combing the report.

Comment: Hey, and welcome to Stack Overflow. To be better able to help you, it would be helpful if you could tell what tool(s) you use for code coverage, and some code snippets. I think it would be helpful to see the code where you call `reset` and `save` :) It might be useful to read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more tips on how to improve questions :)